# com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

После установки Андроид студио выводится такая ошибка:

```
 Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
 Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
```

Погуглив нашел решения этому:

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

Как несложно догадаться, я что-то отключил. Что же я отключил, я не смог понять (гугл не помог). Так чего же я лишил свое приложение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AAPT2 - Android-плагин для gradle, осуществляющий инкрементальную сборку ресурсов.
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0.html

А вообще - загляните в лог, о котором упоминается в тексте ошибки.

Comment: а чем это грозит приложению?

Comment: @user8978194 при запуске проект будет собираться заново, а не обновлять те модули, в которые были внесены изменения